# 2 django models primary key and foreign key

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I am in a need to set a model with a primary key and a foreign key. The same with a second model.

The first model has by default the tcu_id set as the primary key:

```
class Tcu(models.Model):
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

The second model has a primary key set to True, and a foreign key from the tcu model:

```
class Sim(models.Model):
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    tcu = models.ForeignKey(Tcu, null=True, blank=True)
```

This is working good, but the problem comes now when I try to add a foreign key to the first model:

```
 class Tcu(models.Model):
        imei = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
        phone_num = models.ForeignKey(Sim, null=True, blank=True)
```

In tcu phone_num = models.ForeignKey(Sim)
NameError: name 'Sim' is not defined

Comment: Have you imported model Sim?

Comment: I can't really understand why you want FKs in both directions here. That doesn't make sense. What is the actual nature of the relationship between Sim and Tcu?

Comment: You are rigth! thankt you! I am testing some features on my localhost

Answer (score 3):

The [Django documentation for the ForeignKey field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) states:

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself.

So in your case, that would be:

```
class Tcu(models.Model):
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    phone_num = models.ForeignKey('Sim', blank = True)

class Sim(models.Model):
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    tcu = models.ForeignKey(Tcu, null=True, blank=True)
```